# Gradle Settings

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[image]

This is my Gradle settings. Whenever I try to open any projects. It just keeps on loading but it never gets loaded. What Gradle settings should I set ?
I actually changed my gradle settings. But I don't know how to undo it

Comment: In the upper left corner of that window, you should search for "Gradle". Why did you change settings anyway?

Comment: The project wasn't building. If I create a new project it builds. but when i open an existing projects, It's not building

Comment: Sounds like you had a different version of Gradle downloading. You should edit the gradle.properties file to make the version the same or independently download and install Gradle

Answer (score 0):

Set Project-level setting to: Use default gradle wrapper.

Comment: The Project never builds when i set to use this default gradle wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect from  the internet and try opening a project. Most likely the lag is caused due to Gradle upgrading behind the scenes. To check what is going on, launch Android studio from the terminal and open a project. The terminal will Show what is going on.